# HMR angular2 - is ngOnDestroy called on services?

Tags: angular, webpack-hmr

I'm writing my own implementation of ngrx/store.
The last major hurdle is to make it work with hmr.

I would like to do some cleanup on my service, before it is replaced with new one, as the result of hmr reloading the app.

Service is annotated with @Injectable, and implements OnDestroy
Unfortunately it seems that ngOnDestroy() is not called, though constructor of new service is fired. Any idea why it might be so?

Workaround question: Is there a way to list services modified by hmr so maybe i can call it manually?

Comment: afaik, ngOnDestroy is specific to components

Comment: according to devs: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11228 this hook is supported on services